# Printing a list of integers as comma separated list of numbers with max 10 per line

Tags: c++, vector, stl, ostream

I have a list of numbers. I would like to print them as comma separated list of numbers, at most 10 numbers per line. The following program snippet puts in the comma separated list of numbers, without using explicit for loop to iterate the vector of integers, may i be able to print 10 numbers at most per line?

```
  std::vector<int> myvector;
  for (int i=1; i<10; ++i) myvector.push_back(i*10);
  stringstream ss;
  std::copy(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(),
       std::ostream_iterator<int>(ss, ", "));
  cout << "list: " << ss.str() << endl;
```

The output appears as (with extra comma at the end):

```
list: 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90,
```

I found a solution to my original problem:

```
  // print at most 6 per line
  int maxperline = 6;
  std::vector<int>::const_iterator i1,i2,i3;
  stringstream ss;
  ss << "list: ";
  for (i1 = myvector.begin(), i2 = myvector.end(); i1 < i2; i1+=maxperline) {
    i3 = min(i2, i1+maxperline);
    std::copy(i1, i3-1, std::ostream_iterator<int>(ss, ", "));
    ss << *(i3-1) << '\n';
  }
  cout << '\n' << ss.str() << endl;
```

The output appears as:

```
list: 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60
70, 80, 90
```

In this approach, we can have flexibility by having maxperline set as value you desire

Comment: future range algorithms may help. In particular `view::chunk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have some `count` of the output item, and use it.

```
int count = 0;
for (int i : myvector) {
  if (count > 0) std::cout << ", ";
  std::cout << i;
  if (count % 10 == 0 && count >0) std::cout << std::endl;
  count++;
}
```

If you *really* want to use [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) you could have an anonymous lambda

```
int count;
std::for_each(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(),
              [&](int i) {
                   if (count > 0) 
                      std::cout << ", ";
                   std::cout << i;
                   if (count % 10 == 0 && count >0)
                      std::cout << std::endl;
                   count++;
              });
```

<sup>(we obviously need `count` and `std::cout` to be captured and closed *by reference* in the closure, hence the `[&]`....)</sup>

but honestly in that particular case it would be pedantic to code using `std::for_each` like above. Using a plain ranged `for` loop like my first example is shorter and more appropriate.

BTW good optimizing compilers (probably including recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -O2 -std=c++11`) would probably optimize the second solution (using `std::for_each`) into something equivalent to the first (using `for`, and *without* allocating a closure).

You could even try coding that fragment in purely [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) (with a different continuation when `count==0` and when `count%10==0` and otherwise)  but that would be sick, unreadable, and compiled less efficiently...

Comment: This will work, but I was looking for a solution using std::copy or similar without using for loop

Comment: I edited my Qs to add my own ans